# Traefik HTTP to HTTPS non-global redirect - is there a better way?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy, traefik, http-redirect

I have recently finished setting up Traefik with multiple configs but haven't been able to find a solution. I am using docker-compose with dynamic configurator and want to correctly redirect http to https.

**tl;dr**: Do I have to declare both http and https entrypoints to redirect http -> https in Traefik? Really? No better way? Not including an entrypoint-based global redirect (not considering that)

For the service `whoami`, to achieve a simple combo of `local service` + `http auth` + `https` + `http redirect` I need the following:

```
whoami:
    ...
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true

      # External
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=https
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt-tls
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=simpleAuth@file

      # External http redirect
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami-http.rule=Host(`whoami.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami-http.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami-http.middlewares=redirect-https@file
      # - traefik.http.routers.whoami-http.middlewares=simpleAuth@file # Do I need it at all?

      # Local
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami-local.rule=Host(`whoami.local`)
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami-local.entrypoints=http
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami-local.middlewares=simpleAuth@file
```

Relevant configs:

```
### Static config:
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: :80
  https:
    address: :443

### Dynamic config:
 middlewares:
    redirect-https:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: false
```

**My question is**:
Is there a better, more concise way to achieve the redirect?
Naturally, outside of redirecting on the entrypoints level as I want to retain per-container control of redirects.

I initially thought that I could do:

```
# External .dev
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.example.com`)
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=http, https
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certresolver=lets-encrypt-tls
      - traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=redirect-https@file
```

However that doesn't work, unfortunately.

I would probably be more ok with it if I could store all of that in the dynamic configuration file, but because `--traefik.enable=ture` creates un-deletable and unmanageable from dynamic configuration routes and services ([seemingly indented](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.2/routing/routers/#tls)), I have to define all routes in the docker-compose file.

Comment: You definitely want an HTTPS endpoint, and you definitely want to define a [RedirectScheme](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/redirectscheme/) if the client requests HTTP (vs. HTTPS).  So what's wrong with defining an HTTP endpoint on your proxy (simply to allow the connection to be redirected)?  What exactly is the "problem"???  Please clarify.  Especially what you mean by "un-deletable and unmanageable"?

Comment: There are two things here.
For the redirect - I'd love to be able to add one line to the entry point (the last code block) and have http redirected to https, without having to define a whole new router.

For the managing - it's impossible to define the routers/services in the dynamic config if they were created from the docker file by the `--traefik.enable=ture` flag